# Azure Function in library

Tags: azure, shared-libraries, azure-functions

I've created an Azure Function project in S2017 and added two function classes Func1 & Func2... when I run this it pickup both functions.... Now I've tried moving Func2 into a class library and reference it from the first project... but now func2 is not picked up.... I've tried to move func2 to another Azure Function project and then reference this from the first project.. but again Func2 is not picked up

Is it not possible to reference function in an assembly making them part of my function app??

Comment: How do you call the func2, and why you want to separate the func1 and func2? As I know, when function run, it found the func and put them into host and execute when you trigger them. So, I am doubt how you want to see func2 pick up?

Comment: I just wanted to create a library of functions (support functions, that I need in different function apps), that I could reference from a function project and have the functions from the library added....

Answer (score 3):

Assuming Visual Studio is being used, if you add:

```
<FunctionsInDependencies>true</FunctionsInDependencies>
```

to the `<PropertyGroup>` in your .csproj it will look for functions in  external libraries and generate the correct metadata.

Answer (score -1):

You seem to need class library rather than functions. Functions are meant to run independent based on triggers such as http, queues, etc. Have a look into durable function if you want to chain functions.